# Reload appcomponent.ts while logging out in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I had a scenario where based on type of user I need to get the side menu.I could achieve this only when we launches the app for first time.After logging out even if type of user changes sidemenu remains the same. Can any one suggest a solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So your question is not the clearest question and in your next question you should add in your code.

From what I understand is that you have multiple user types and want a specific menu for each of them.

You can create something like this in your `app.component.html`

```
<ion-list *ngIf="user.role = 'admin'">
  <!-- admin menu -->
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngIf="user.role = 'default'">
  <!-- default menu -->
</ion-list>
```

Or even make it item specific

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>Home</ion-item> <!-- all users -->
  <ion-item *ngIf="user.role = 'admin'">Analytics</ion-item> <!-- admin only -->
</ion-list>
```

Now we need to keep track of the user role itself.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

....

export class AppComponent {
   user: any = {role: 'default'}; //declare it or do something smarter with the menu

   constructor(private events: Events) {
      this.events.subscribe('user:changed', user => {
         // will update the user and immediately change menu accordingly
         this.user = user; 
      });
   }
}
```

and then in your login function:

```
login() {
   let user = this.myApi.login(this.username, this.encryptedPass);

   // will trigger the function from app.component.ts
   this.events.publish('user:changed', user); 
}
```

Useful links:

- [Ionic's Events docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)
- [Ionic's MenuController docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/components/menu/MenuController/) (allows you to control multiple menus in a smart way)

Comment: Better solution would probably be to use the `MenuController` and enable/disable menus via that controller